# Cleanup .plist files after update

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I have an app that stores some static data inside a `.plist` file.

I've made some changes to those files adding some stuff... I'm currently testing this update for the app in testflight, and looks like the updated `.plist` files are not used, while the old version is still loaded (if you have the current AppStore version installed).

Can I programmatically clean this "cache" at the first start of the new version and force the new files to be used?

Or should I rename everything? (Which I consider only as a last resort).

Thanks!

Comment: If this plist is in your app bundle (as a resource), it should be updated.  Double-check that the IPA contains the updated plist.

Comment: @Avi it does. But there's some other kind of cache (maybe programmatically created, It's not an app I wrote) I need to remove. Thanks for the suggestion BTW)